# What is the name for sorting a directory with lots of files into subdirectories?

Tags: best-practices, directory

One way to make manageable a directory with a huge number of files into it is to sort the files into subdirectories named after progressive characters in the files' names.

E.g.:

```
- a8debcdcf0d2302ccde5a43bb1fb385e81098342.jpg
- 91ff48de8cfc6468bdc2115cf87cfb6547eee713.jpg
- 99d002e2065cdf02bd6d04bf29a8230564719b76.jpg
...
```

The above files get sorted into subdirectories similarly to this:

```
- a/
  - 8/
    - a8debcdcf0d2302ccde5a43bb1fb385e81098342.jpg
- 9/
  - 1/
    - 91ff48de8cfc6468bdc2115cf87cfb6547eee713.jpg
  - 9/
    - 99d002e2065cdf02bd6d04bf29a8230564719b76.jpg
```

There are several variations on this method, such as using a different number of characters to name subdirectories or using a hash or other algorithm to determine the path to each file.

Is there a formal name for this method of organizing files?

Answer (score 4):

I've always called it hash-chunking.

There are a couple of things to keep in mind with structures like this:

- Each directory creates an inode. If you chunk on each character, a single file could cause, say, 33 inodes to be created. You'll run out of inodes before you run out of space that way.
- If you chunk on groups (say, first n-characters, followed by second n-characters) keep your sets small enough you're not forcing inodes to extend, which will slow lookups.
- If your hash is significantly random, the 3rd and further order chunks are practically never going to have siblings, so you may be able to chunk like... 1234/5678/901234567890etc and keep your inodes small.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's just called "hashed directory structure", for example at http://michaelandrews.typepad.com/the_technical_times/2009/10/creating-a-hashed-directory-structure.html :

> How can one store a large number of files while maintaining a high level of performance during access? One solution is file name hashing.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a  **[B-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree)** (not related to binary tree).

Comment: I wouldn't call this is a B-tree, at least not in the traditional meaning of the term. The point of a B-tree is that it is wide (with possibly many sub-trees under each node) but also that it is self-balancing (nodes can split and merge). Here you just create the nodes based on the file names, with no balancing.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Usually in these particular structures the depth is consistent between nodes so there's balancing/merging/splitting.